# Select an option containing accents with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I have a `select` element. Some `option` may contain accents, so to display them properly I've converted them to HTML entities.

```
<select id="someid">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>Option one</option>
    <option>Option tw&ograve;</option>
</select>
```

My goal is to select one of the given options with jQuery.
If the chosen option doesn't contain accents, everything works fine.

```
$("#someid").val("Option one"); // works
```

But when I try to select an option containing accents, it fails.

```
$("#someid").val("Option tw&ograve;"); // fails
```

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ykwqocj/) showing the problem.
How can I select an option containing accents?

Comment: You need to use the actual character in the value: `$("#someid").val("Option twò");` http://jsfiddle.net/2ykwqocj/1/

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I've added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the actual character in the value in jQuery:

```
$("#someid").val("Option twò");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ykwqocj/1/)